# Calculating freefalling object's height

Tags: c++, beginner

This is the code for my first CS1 project, I hope to be posting my code here to track my progress of learning the language of C++.  I shouldn't be too shabby, since I know C considerably well and have reviewed C++ code here before.

> Write a program that allows the user to enter a time in seconds and
>   then outputs how far an object would drop if it is in freefall for
>   that length of time.  Assume that the object starts at rest, there is
>   no friction or resistance from air, and there is a constant
>   acceleration of 32 feet per second due to gravity.  Use the equation:
>
> $$
> \text{distance} = \dfrac{\text{acceleration} \cdot\text{time}^2}{2}
> $$

**`rock.cpp`**:

```
/**
 * @file rock.cpp
 * @brief Determines the height that a rock falls (in feet) after a given time
 * @author syb0rg
 * @date 9/8/14
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(void)
{
    // initialize variables on declaration
    double time = 0;
    double acceleration = 32.174;

    std::cout << "Enter the time in seconds that a rock will fall: ";
    std::cin >> time;

    double feetFallen = (acceleration * pow(time, 2)) / 2;

    std::cout << "The rock fell " << feetFallen << " feet." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Really, you need to add comments for each line. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is both short and good, so there's not much to say.

#### Header organization

It's a good idea to keep your headers organized. Keeping them alphabetically ordered allows you to spot accidental duplicates.

#### `main()` signature

You don't need to put `void` in the parentheses. It's very much a C-ism, and is not necessary in C++. Empty parentheses also means the function takes no arguments.

#### `const` variables and constants

`acceleration` is a constant, and should be marked `constexpr` to indicate it is a compile-time constant. Please note that `constexpr` is only available in C++11 or later. If you have to use an earlier version, you can replace it with `static const` for largely the same effect. `feetFallen` should be marked `const`, since you only read from it after it is initialized.

Marking variables `const` and constants `constexpr` limits the number of moving parts in your application, making it easier to reason about and keep correct.

#### Unnecessary comment

Your comment about initialization is not necessary. The fact that you initialize variables the same time they are declared is obvious from reading the code.

#### Invalid user input

`time` will contain the value `0` if your user inputs non-numeric input. If you want to constrain the user to numeric-only input, you can loop until the user enters only a valid number. Inspired by [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10829026/1601291), your solution could look like this:

```
while(!(std::cin >> time)){
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::cout << "Invalid input.  Please enter a number: ";
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about `constexpr`, good tip!  [As for that one comment...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17624464#17624464)

Comment: @syb0rg Ah. I don't hang out in chat, so I didn't see that. You have my condolences.

Comment: It's fine, I didn't expect you to see that. But it is definitely a place you should hang out more ;)

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to the [associative property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) of multiplication, *and the fact that you're working with all `double` values here*, you don't need parentheses around `acceleration * pow(time, 2)`, so instead of:

> ```
> double feetFallen = (acceleration * pow(time, 2)) / 2;
> ```

You can write:

```
double feetFallen = acceleration * pow(time, 2) / 2;
```

Of course, if some of the operands had been `int` values, you'd have to be careful.

Answer (score 10):

- No `void` parameters are needed in C++, unlike in C.
- You can improve variable scope a bit more.  If `time` is just to be inputted by the user, then you can declare it between the prompt and input.

  ```
  std::cout << "Enter the time in seconds that a rock will fall: ";
  double time;
  std::cin >> time;
  ```

  In addition, consider accepting a command line argument if one is given (other than the executable).  Otherwise, you can still have the user input a `time` via `cin`.

  ```
  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  {
      double time;

      // the executable is considered an arg
      if (argc == 1)
      {
          std::cout << "Enter the time in seconds that a rock will fall: ";
          std::cin >> time;
      }
      // other args are given
      else
      {
          // take the second arg only
          // the string has to be converted
          time = std::atof(argv[1]);
      }

      // ...
  }
  ```
- Assuming `acceleration` is not meant to change, you can make it `const`:

  ```
  const double acceleration = 32.174;
  ```
- You *probably* can avoid a slight performance hit with `pow()` here by just doing `time * time`:

  ```
  double feetFallen = (acceleration * time * time) / 2;
  ```

Comment: For your `time * time` point - I avoided doing this because `pow()` handled "malicious" input better (such as me inputting a letter, a negative number, etc.)

Comment: @syb0rg: Fair enough, and I did sort of figure you already knew this.  Going by rolfl's (joking) comment, you could've commented about that.

Answer (score 7):

If you really want the code to execute efficiently, you should write

```
double feetFallen = 0.5 * acceleration * pow(time, 2);
```

instead of

> ```
> double feetFallen = (acceleration * pow(time, 2)) / 2;
> ```

This lets the compiler embed the constant (16.087) instead of two constants (0.5 and 32.174) in the binary, and saves a multiplication at runtime.  This is true whether or not you declare `acceleration` as `const` or `constexpr` — although it's good practice to mark it as a constant anyway.  Personally, I would also rename `acceleration` in a way that indicates its units.

You might think that writing `time * time` would be more efficient than `pow(time, 2)`, but it turns out that both Clang and GCC optimize `pow(time, 2)` as a simple multiplication instead of a function call when `-O1` is enabled.  So, it's really just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 5):

A small point added to what has already been said: don't use `std::endl`, use `'\n'` unless you are really sure that you want to force `std::cout` to flush; and in that case also think about why you want it to flush.

```
std::cout << "The rock fell " << feetFallen << " feet.\n";
```

Comment: Why wouldn't I want it to flush there?

Comment: Might not make much difference here, but if a program prints 100,000 lines of text, it makes a difference in speed.